# Splitting dataframe column in multiple columns using json_normalize does not work

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` created through an import from a mysql-db

```
ID                                      CONFIG
0              276  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...
1              349  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...
2              378  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...
3              381  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...
4              385  {"pos":[{"type":"geo...
```

where the elements in the `CONFIG` column all have the form:

```
{"posit":[{"type":"geo_f","priority":1,"validity":0},{"type":"geo_m","priority":2,"validity":0},{"type":"geo_i","priority":3,"validity":0},{"type":"geo_c","priority":4,"validity":0}]}
```

Now, I was convinced these elements are `json`-type elements and tried the following method to transform them into columns:

```
df_new = pd.json_normalize(df['CONFIG'])
```

However, this return the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

What am I missing? Thankful for any help!

**EDIT: Full Traceback**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-23db4c0afdab> in <module>
----> 1 df_new = pd.json_normalize(df['CONFIG'])

c:\users\s-degossondevarennes\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py in _json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep, max_level)
    268 
    269     if record_path is None:
--> 270         if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
    271             # naive normalization, this is idempotent for flat records
    272             # and potentially will inflate the data considerably for

c:\users\s-degossondevarennes\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    268 
    269     if record_path is None:
--> 270         if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
    271             # naive normalization, this is idempotent for flat records
    272             # and potentially will inflate the data considerably for

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: The code is correct. What is your PD version?

Comment: the version of pandas is 1.2.4

Comment: I got it, your ```{"pos":[{"type":"geo...``` is ```'{"pos":[{"type":"geo...'```

Comment: Possibly because the values in `CONFIG` column are not truly dictinoaries but strings. You can try `import ast; df.CONFIG = df.CONFIG.apply(ast.literal_eval)` first and then normalize.

Comment: @MustafaAydın: Ok. This solves part of the issue. Now ```json_normalize()``` produces a column ```pos``` with its elements being lists of dictionaries.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes sorry, I'm not super familiar with these JSON things but `pd.json_normalize(df['CONFIG'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x)["posit"]).explode())` where we first reach the `posit` key of the dictionaries and then explode the so-formed lists prior to normalizing seems to do something.

Comment: @MustafaAydın: BRILLIANT! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is the values in `CONFIG` column are strings in disguise. So, a `literal_eval` can make them true dictionaries. Then, they are all indexed with `"posit"` key first that we better get rid of. But then we are left with `list`s; so `explode` comes in. Overall,

```
from ast import literal_eval

pd.json_normalize(df['CONFIG'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x)["posit"]).explode())
```

I get (for a 1-row sample data)

```
    type  priority  validity
0  geo_f         1         0
1  geo_m         2         0
2  geo_i         3         0
3  geo_c         4         0
```